# print absolut path of symbolic links for Cscope

Tags: linux, find, symlink, cscope

Since cscope won't follow (relative) symbolic links I need a technic to
collect the absolut paths behind the (relative) symbolic links.

Example:

Wehen I'll find all the c files within a directory I use the find command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

LNX="/home/cabs/BUILD-ENV/Android_C1/kernel"
FILELOC="/home/cabs/BUILD-ENV/Scope_C1"
ANDROID="/home/cabs/BUILD-ENV/Android_C1"

echo "Android Files"

find $ANDROID  \
-path "$ANDROID/bionic" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/bootable" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/build" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/dalvik" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/development" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/device" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/external" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/frameworks" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/hardware" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/packages" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/system" -prune -o \
-path "$ANDROID/vendor" -prune -o \
-name '*.java' -print -o \
-name '*.aidl' -print -o \
-name '*.hpp' -print -o \
-name '*.cpp'  -print -o \
-name '*.xml'  -print -o \
-name '*.mk'  -print -o \
-name '*.[chxsS]' \
#-print >$FILELOC/cscope.files
```

Now I'll get a file with all the desired pathes.

**An example entry:**

*/home/cabs/BUILD-ENV/Android_C1/prebuilts/ndk/6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/arpa/nameser.h*

But this entry could be a symlink. (which cannot be procecced by cscope)

The symlink could look like the following example:

*/home/cabs/BUILD-ENV/Android_C1/prebuilts/ndk/6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/arpa/nameser.h -> ../../../../../../platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/include/arpa/nameser.h*

How could the 'cscope.files' file be parsed, so that the original entry (points to the symlink) would be replaced with the absolute path of the file behind the symlink?strong text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `readlink` or `realpath` should do the trick.

```
readlink -f symlinkName
realpath symlinkName
```

You can use them directly in your `find` command.
Example :

```
find . -exec realpath {} \;
```